# php cli overwrites the previous instance

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to create multiple instances of the same script to help process a very large file. Below is my code snippet:

```
        for($i =0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {
            $offset = $i*$thread_data_size;
            $data_slice = array_slice($file_array,$offset,$thread_data_size);
            $data_serialized = serialize($data_slice);
            $data_serialized = str_replace('"', '\"',$data_serialized);

      $root ='/data/web/stage.shiprequest.com/public/async_processes/hubit/';
      $scriptfilename = $root.'phptest2.php';
      $cmd = "nohup nice -n 10 /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php.ini -f $scriptfilename \"$data_serialized\" \"$origacctcode\" \"$compcode\" \"$uid\" \"$mode\" \"$batchId\" \"$hubid\" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & ";

            sleep(1);
            $output = shell_exec($cmd);
        }
```

The problem is for the the server to create multiple instances of the script (phptest2.php), I have to put a sleep(1) between my loop executions. If I dont put sleep(1), the server only executes the script only once and it is the last instance of the script that gets executed (i.e. the instance of the script invoked when $i=5). This is as if I request the server to execute the same script too fast multiple times, it overwrites my previous requests........ However, the server does not overwrite the previous request if it has enough time to instantiate the first instance of the script requested.

I dont want to have to sleep between my loops. Any workarounds??!  . .

Thanks, Sumit

Comment: done this before, no sleep required, exec() was used, could try that.

Comment: I just tried exec as well. shell_exec and exec are basically same . . . exec allows to pass back return values. Anyway exec did not solve the problem.

Comment: tried it with out the loop, just write the five lines

Comment: its not feasible in my case to do it without the loop . . . I am just doing 5 times to present the point  . . . but in reality how many times the loop is executed is dependent on how big of a file I have to process